# UITableView scroll not working properly when inset content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to add some inset to tableView to padding all your content. When im using only Top/Bottom content, all works fine. But trying to put left and right values, the tableView scroll dont work (see gif). What is wrong?

```
     @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.tableView.clipsToBounds = true
    let insets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 20, right: 20)
    self.tableView.contentInset = insets
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check constraint properly. and unselect Bounce Horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you simply to separate top-bottom and left-right insets:
you can add top-bottom insets to the table view and 
left-right insets to your cells as constraints to content view.

This way scroll will work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have wrong understanding how `UIScrollView's` `contentInset` works in scope of `UITableView`.
[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619406-contentinset) says next about `UIScrollView's` `contentInset`:

> Use this property to extend the space between your content and the edges of the content view. The unit of size is points. The default value is UIEdgeInsetsZero.
>   By default, UIKit automatically adjusts the content inset to account for overlapping bars. You use this property to extend that distance even further, perhaps to accommodate your own custom content. Get the total adjustment—that is, the safe area plus your custom insets—using the adjustedContentInset property. To change how the safe area is applied, modify the contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior property.

So, setting `contentInset` do not actually modify `contentSize`. For instance, pay your attention how vertical content insets are changed when you install your view controller inside `UINavigationController`. By default, `UIScrollView` automatically modify `contentInset` to move content downwards in order to `UINavigationBar` does not overlap your content.

Starting from iOS 11 there is even more advanced APIs to work with safe areas, please find it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_relative_to_the_safe_area).

As for your problem, you need to modify `UIScrollView's` `contentSize` somehow in order to achieve desired behaviour. `UITableView` does not provide such API and table view's `contentSize` equals table view bound's size.

From my perspective there are three possible options:

1. You could change your `UITableViewCell` view's hierarchy by adding another `contentView` with transparent background on top of `UITableViewCell`. Then make `contentView's` size smaller than superview's size and finally place all other UI components on top of content view.
2. You could switch from `UITableView` to `UICollectionView` and use custom layout (you could use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`). You can easily make it look like `UITableView` layout and set different insets for items and sections and even calculate custom `contentSize`.
3. You can play with layout cycle, override layout cycle methods and set new `contentSize` to your `UITableView`, but I would not recommend to do that. Final solution could not be obvious and make code base messy.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

A possible easy solution could be to add a padding using constraints in storyboard:

[image]

Comment: This is not a solution because the scrollable are it will be only the centered tableView. In my cause all the view, included the area with padding, has to be scrollable.